# How to extract port number from shellcode

Tags: assembly, shellcode

I saw [this](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/e6a741011fed35d97ceb734e1b31e6e58507a9a3/external/source/shellcode/windows/x86/src/block/block_reverse_tcp.asm#L41) shellcode and when they use the `connect` function they pass the port number 4444:

```
set_address:
  push byte 0x05         ; retry counter
  push 0x0100007F        ; host 127.0.0.1
  push 0x5C110002        ; family AF_INET and port 4444
  mov esi, esp           ; save pointer to sockaddr struct
```

Or in [other website](https://coffeegist.com/security/slae-exam-5-shellcode-analysis-part-3/) like that:

```
0000001A      push dword 0x5c110002   ; [0x5c110002, 0x81caa8c0, 0x1, 0x0] // sin_port and sin_family (4444, 0x0002)
```

But they push `0x5C110002`, how they extract 4444 from `0x5C110002`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `connect` syscall takes a `sockaddr` structure as an argument, which looks something like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
        short   sin_family;
        u_short sin_port;
        struct  in_addr sin_addr;
        char    sin_zero[8];
};
```

They aren't extracting 4444, it's simply passed on the stack as a two-byte short. You are passing to `connect`, in little-endian order:

- `sin_family: 0x0002 (AF_INET)`
- `sin_port: 0x5c11 (4444 in hex, little endian)`
- `sin_addr: 0x0100007F ([127] [0] [0] [1], little endian)`

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/39152) how to convert it with python.

```
import socket
port = 4444
hex(socket.htons(port))
Result : 0x5c11
```

The opposite is like that:

```
socket.htons(0x5c11)
```